# Node/express app skips user authentication middleware and goes straight to callback

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware `isAuthenticated` to ensure that the user is logged in before he can post a comment:

```
function isAuthenticated(req,res,next) {

    req.isAuthenticated ? next() : res.redirect('/login');
}
```

This middleware is suppose to be running here:

```
router.post('/cat/:id', isAuthenticated, function(req,res) {

    console.log('not suppose to be here');

    var id = req.params.id;

    Cat.findById(id, function(err, cat) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else {

            var id = req.params.id;
            var comment = new Comment({
                username: req.user.username,
                content: req.body.content
            });
 //more code
```

However, when I try to post a comment without logging in, my app crashes and the console shows the following:

```
not suppose to be here
username: req.user.username,
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

I refactored all the routes into a separate file, and exported it to app.js. All routes pertaining to cats are stored in `cats.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var Cat = require('../models/cat.js');
var Comment = require('../models/comment.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


router.use(function(req,res,next) {

    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});

function isAuthenticated(req,res,next) {

    req.isAuthenticated ? next() : res.redirect('/login');
}

router.get('/cat/:id', function(req,res) {

    var id = req.params.id;

    Cat.findById(id, function(err, cat) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else {

               Comment.find({}, function(err, comments) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);

                } else {
                     res.render('show', {cat:cat, comments:comments});
                }
            });        
        }
    });  
});

//more code

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**:

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config/config.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Cat = require('./models/cat.js');
var Comment = require('./models/comment.js');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var User = require('./models/user.js');



mongoose.connect(config.dbURL, function(err) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('successfully connected to database!');
    }
});


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(session({
    secret:"sfsdfsdfsd",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static('public'));


var authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.js');
var catRoutes = require('./routes/cats.js');


app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(catRoutes);
```

Why is my middleware being bypassed? Please ask for additional code if it's needed.

**Edit1**: Updated to provide more information.

Comment: How is the request data being sent?  Is it using form encoding?  You may need to use an additional midleware like [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to extract those fields from the request.  Where is `user` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Yes, I am using bodyParser. Do you suggest I post the full code instead?

Comment: At least the code that defines `user`.  Your error is saying that you are using a property of `user` and that `user` is undefined.  Does it come from the `isAuthenticated` middleware?

Comment: Please have a look at the edit.  provided more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I just forgot to call  `req.isAuthenticated` in my middleware. I had it as:

```
function isAuthenticated(req,res,next) {

    req.isAuthenticated ? next() : res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Whereas it should have been `req.isAuthenticated()`.